# Eclipse with ADT - JUnit Test Not Running With EclEmma

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, adt, eclemma

I am currently running Eclipse Juno with the Android Development Tools plugin so I can develop Android applications and test them. To get code coverage of the applications (and preferably the APIs of Android themselves), I installed EclEmma into Eclipse, but just when I was about to run it for the first time, it gives me an error:

```
Error while dumping coverage data (code 5013).
Socket closed
```

I don't know what might be causing this, and when I looked it up [here](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21420748), the workaround didn't seem to work or I'm just not sure where those directories it mentioned are when dealing with the Android SDK. Anyone deal with similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of **EclEmma** use [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/), which as far as I know doesn't support off-line instrumentation.
You should try to find a pre-Jacoco version of **EclEmma** (it was working just one year ago, http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/07/eclipse-android-and-emma-code-coverage.html) and try to install it on Juno (very unlikely to work) or stick to the HTML reports, wich can be opened in Eclipse, so it's no such a big problem.

Comment: And how do I set it to just do HTML reports?

Comment: Just forget about EclEmma and use android

Comment: Yes, just try 'ant help' in your android project (after converting it to ant using android command)

Comment: And that will give me coverage of my application under test _and_ the source code? It's important that I get both.